# How to make download files only available on login on Joomla! 1.5.23?

Tags: php, joomla, authentication, membership, download

I'm sure this is a minor problem but I just want to get some opinion on this one. Using Joomla! 1.5.23. It's a member site. There are some pdf up for download on some pages. On specific pages pdf files under that must require one to be logged in. How do I do that without having to make the page restricted? Anyone can browse the page but once they start to click on the pdfs for download they have to login. How do I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a document manager extension, like DOCman for example: https://www.joomlatools.com/extensions/docman/.

You can insert links to private documents in your articles that redirect the visitor to a login page before they can download.

Unfortunately support for Joomla 1.5 is deprecated, upgrading your Joomla site is advised.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want this in your joomla content  component. So first you need to made some changes in joomla template in /templates/your_templatename/html/com_content/article/default.php and create a new user instant

```
<?php $user = JFactory::getUser();?>
```

find this line in a if statement

```
if($this->params->get('show_pdf_icon'))
```

put this line with and statement like this

```
if($this->params->get('show_pdf_icon') && !empty($user->id))
```

If user is login then and then it can show pdf icon. You can put this in any icon you want to show for user login